# Generating Random Strings

Tags: r, random

I want to generate random strings in the following way: `ABCDE1234E`, i.e each string contains 5 Characters, 4 Numerics, then 1 Char.

I figured out a way to create this using the following code.

```
library(random)
string_5 <- as.vector(randomStrings(n=5000, len=5, digits=FALSE, upperalpha=TRUE,
                        loweralpha=FALSE, unique=TRUE, check=TRUE))
number_4 <- as.vector(randomNumbers(n=5000, min=1111, max=9999, col=5, base=10, check=TRUE))
string_1 <- as.vector(randomStrings(n=5000, len=1, digits=FALSE, upperalpha=TRUE,
                         loweralpha=FALSE, unique=FALSE, check=TRUE))
PAN.Number <- paste(string_5,number_4,string_1,sep = "")
```

But these functions are taking a long time and the `random` library needs a network connection.

```
> system.time(string_5 <- as.vector(randomStrings(n=5000, len=5, digits=FALSE, upperalpha=TRUE,
+                                                 loweralpha=FALSE, unique=TRUE, check=TRUE)))
   user  system elapsed 
   0.07    0.00    3.18
```

Is there any method that I could try to reduce the execution time?
I also tried using `sample()` but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using "stringi" as suggested by @akrun will be faster, but the following is also very fast and does not require any additional packages:

```
myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
  a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
  paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
}
```

Example output:

```
myFun(10)
##  [1] "BZHOF3737P" "EPOWI0674X" "YYWEB2825M" "HQIXJ5187K" "IYIMB2578R"
##  [6] "YSGBG6609I" "OBLBL6409Q" "PUMAL5632D" "ABRAT4481L" "FNVEN7870Q"
```

Answer (score 33):

We can use `stri_rand_strings` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
sprintf("%s%s%s", stri_rand_strings(5, 5, '[A-Z]'),
      stri_rand_strings(5, 4, '[0-9]'), stri_rand_strings(5, 1, '[A-Z]'))
```

---

Or more compactly

```
do.call(paste0, Map(stri_rand_strings, n=5, length=c(5, 4, 1),
            pattern = c('[A-Z]', '[0-9]', '[A-Z]')))
```

#### Benchmarks

```
system.time({
    do.call(paste0, Map(stri_rand_strings, n=5000, length=c(5, 4, 1),
            pattern = c('[A-Z]', '[0-9]', '[A-Z]')))
    })
#  user  system elapsed 
#   0      0      0
```

Was able to reproduce the timings even for one part of the expected output using OP's method

```
system.time(string_5 <- as.vector(randomStrings(n=5000, len=5, digits=FALSE, upperalpha=TRUE,
                                              loweralpha=FALSE, unique=TRUE, check=TRUE)))
#  user  system elapsed 
#   0.86    0.24    5.52
```

Answer (score 12):

You can directly perform what you want:
Sample random 5 capital letters
Sample 4 digits
Sample 1 random capital letter

```
digits = 0:9
createRandString<- function() {
  v = c(sample(LETTERS, 5, replace = TRUE),
        sample(digits, 4, replace = TRUE),
        sample(LETTERS, 1, replace = TRUE))
  return(paste0(v,collapse = ""))
}
```

This will be more easily controlled, and won't take as long.

Answer (score 3):

Your performance problem comes from using the `random` package in the first place: it's understandable that you could find the `random::randomStrings()` function in an internet search and think it's a good way to generate random strings for use in a program, but the `random` package is **not intended for general-purpose programming**. It works by querying the [RANDOM.ORG](https://www.random.org/) server, which is intrinsically slower than R's built-in pseudo-random number generators.

From one of the [vignettes from the random package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/random/vignettes/random-intro.pdf):

> There are a number of situations in which it is desirable to use non-deterministically determined
>   random numbers. Examples include 
>   - to seed distributed computing on different nodes with truly indepedent seeds;
>   - to obtain portable initializations for RNGs that do not depend on particular operating system
>   or hardware features;
>   - to validate simulation results using non-deterministic random numbers;
>   
>   - to provide indeterministic seeds used for lottery drawings or games ...

Note that most of these examples are about *seeding* or *initializing* (these are synonyms) R's built-in pseudo-random number generators, rather than replacing them ...

Answer (score 2):

We can now do this with "rowwise" and "mutate" from dplyr, with library(stringi) for the stri_rand_strings function:

```
df %>% 
rowwise() %>% 
mutate(unique_id = paste0(stri_rand_strings(1, 5, "[A-Z]"), stri_rand_strings(1, 4, "[0-9]"), stri_rand_strings(1, 1, "[A-Z]")))
```

This avoids the need to create a function.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone came here looking for a way to generate random file names, here's what I used. I like it for its elegance

```
library(dplyr)
runif(1, 1000000000000, 9999999999999) %>% round %>% as.character %>% paste0("/tmp/", ., ".png")
```

Note: you can easily change how many random strings it generates by changing the `1` in `runif()` to the number you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ASCII table to get a fine control of your final string.

```
randString <- function(characters=0, numbers=0, symbols=0, lowerCase=0, upperCase=0) {
  ASCII <- NULL
  if(symbols>0)    ASCII <- c(ASCII, sample(c(33:47, 58:34, 91:96, 123:126), symbols))
  if(numbers>0)    ASCII <- c(ASCII, sample(48:57, numbers))
  if(upperCase>0)  ASCII <- c(ASCII, sample(65:90, upperCase))
  if(lowerCase>0)  ASCII <- c(ASCII, sample(97:122, lowerCase))
  if(characters>0) ASCII <- c(ASCII, sample(c(65:90, 97:122), characters))
  
  return( rawToChar(as.raw(sample(ASCII, length(ASCII)))) )
}
```

Example:

```
randString(characters=5, numbers=4)
# [1] "9fKW75o1N"
```

Comment: that was very useful, thanks! one only note, in this row: ```if(symbols>0)    ASCII <- c(ASCII, sample(c(33:47, 58:34, 91:96, 123:126), symbols))```, it should be ```58:64```