# Creating a vector with random letters

Tags: r

I want to create some example data and started as follows;

`dat <- as.data.frame(runif(100, 0, 3000))`

Now I would like to do the same thing, but create a character vector, something like:

`dat <- as.data.frame(runif(100, A, Z))`

What would be the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Are you looking for `dat2 <- as.data.frame(sample(LETTERS, 100, replace = TRUE))`? If you want random 'words' (strings of letters) you could try the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/42734547/12957340

Comment: I was indeed looking for sample in combination with `LETTERS`, I didn't know it was that simple! Thank you very much!

Comment: There are also some randomisation functions in the `stringi` package - `stri_rand_strings(100, 1, "[A-Z]")`.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Thank you, I was already looking for a way to limit the range of letters haha.

Comment: If you wanted "real" words there are plenty of lists available on the internet (e.g. https://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/bncfreq/flists.html) from which you could sample after filtering by word length for example.